# Is there a way to find highly expressed genes in clusters using kmeans?

Tags: r, k-means

I have a data set this looks something like the image below but is much larger (thousands of genes):

[dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/89tw1.png)

I ran the kmeans on this data using R and have the samples separated into two clusters. Now I am trying to find the genes that are highly expressed in each cluster. I thought maybe making a heatmap may work, but I couldn't figure it out or if there was a better method to use. My question is: is there a way to find the highly expressed genes in each cluster?

I am writing commands to the R console to analyze the data by the way.

Thank you!

Comment: It would help if you provided example data that we could use to answer your question. However, you might try something like `aggregate(DATA, by=list(CLUSTER), mean)` to get the mean value of each gene expression by cluster.

Comment: Hey chimmy, can you provide an example of your data? What did you run kmeans on?